# How does the "Add the Store Code To Url" work?

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to implement a similar one but concatenating some string to the default store code?

Example: 
I go to **site.com/code**
but I want to show *store view code = **code1***

Answer (score 0):

In admin goto Store -> Configuration -> Web -> Url Option

Add Store Code to Urls = Yes

Clear cache.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that. But my question was another one?